# Animejs with angular directive ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, anime.js

I am starting to use animejs and I would like to include an animation in my Angular application.

While trying so, I have found out that the animation does not work when the `div` where the animation is placed depends on the directive `ngIf`. The image correctly loads when the condition in ngIf is true but it is not animated. Removing the directive solves the problem but I want to show it conditionally.

JS:

```
var value = 2;

anime({
  targets: '#rod',
  translateX: 70,
  easing: 'linear',
  loop: true
});
```

CSS:

```
#rod{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML working fine:

```
<div id="rod">
</div>
```

HTML not animating:

```
<div id="rod" *ngIf="value > 0">
</div>
```

HTML not working either:

```
<div *ngIf="value > 0">
    <div id="rod">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything I should be doing to make the animation work with the Angular directive?
I am using Angular 8.2.14.

Comment: Do you have component.ts file ? value should be part of the component

Comment: @Ininiv Yes but I chose to include as little code as possible. Value does get recognized because `rod` is correctly shown/hidden according to the condition in ngIf. The problem is the lack of animation.

Comment: Can you please try using [hidden] attribute?

Comment: @AmanGojariya However, I still don't know why `ngIf` doesn't work. Do you have any clue?

Comment: It seems because of using *ngIf HTML is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Using *ngIf HTML is not render so the animation is not working with that. Can you please try using **[hidden]** attribute?

Hope this helps!

Thank you.

Comment: HTML is rendered because the color block described in the CSS file is correctly shown/hidden according to the condition in ngIf. The only problem in the lack of animation. I do not know if there is some kind of incompatibility between animejs and Angular directives.

Comment: You can also use <div id="rod">
    <div *ngIf="value > 0">
    </div>
</div>
Hope this helps!